# Can I use Armory without having the Blockchain in my laptop?

Tags: blockchain, armory, storage-footprint

I just started (*to try*) to use Bitcoin and the first issue I face is that **I need to download the 100+ GB blockchain** in order to use any of the wallets, such as **[Armory](https://btcarmory.com/)**. This can take a very long time due to my internet speed.

I successfully installed bitcoin and bitcoin-qt in my laptop, as well as Armory, but now I have to download the blockchain in order to be able to make any transaction.

So I wonder, Is there any possibility to use Bitcoin (and have a wallet, client, such as Armory) for buying and selling bitcoins without having the entire blockchain downloaded in my laptop ?

PS: I'm new to this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Armory requires you to download the entire blockchain. You cannot use pruning either as Armory requires the entire blockchain to be present in order for it to work properly.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. doing some more searching I realized on bitcoin.org that in all available wallets are specified whether it needs or not the entire blockchain under the feature "Simplified validation" (which means it does not need the entire blockchain), which is not the case of Armory.

Comment: An alternative could be use another wallet such as [Electrum](https://electrum.org)

Comment: Simplified validation is orthogonal to storing the chain. Bitcoin Core does full validation, but does require storing the whole chain.